# Problem with boost::variant, linker giving a segfault

Tags: c++, g++, segmentation-fault, boost-variant

I have a boost variant with 7 types in it. When I try to use the last two types, the linker segfaults. I am using g++ (gcc version 3.3.3 on SuSE Linux)  on a 64 bit linux machine and the error that I get is

```
collect2: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault]
```

It doesnt matter what order I put the types in, the last two will cause a segfault when I try to use them. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Code:

```
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class1::Ptr> Class1Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class2::Ptr> Class2Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class3::Ptr> Class3Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class4::Ptr> Class4Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class5::Ptr> Class5Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class6::Ptr> Class6Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class7::Ptr> Class7Tuple;

typedef boost::variant< Class1Tuple, Class2Tuple, Class3Tuple,
                        Class4Tuple, Class5Tuple, Class6Tuple,
                        Class7Tuple > ClassTupleItem;
```

ClassX::Ptr is a boost shared pointer to that class. Ptr is defined as a typedef inside the class itself as below

```
struct Class1
{
 typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class1> Ptr;
    ...
    ...
}
```

when I try to use the last two types in the boost variant as in

```
Class1Tuple tup("str", pointer);
ClassTupleItem(tup); // works fine since I used Class1Tuple

Class6Tuple tup2("str", pointer2);
ClassTupleItem(tup2); // causes a segfault.
```

if I define the boost::variant as (interchange Class6 and Class1)

```
typedef boost::variant< Class6Tuple, Class2Tuple, Class3Tuple,
                        Class4Tuple, Class5Tuple, Class1Tuple,
                        Class7Tuple > ClassTupleItem;
```

then I get a segfault when compiling this code

```
Class1Tuple tup("str", pointer);
ClassTupleItem(tup); // worked earlier
```

Comment: Post code please. This isn't enough information to diagnose the problem.

Comment: The actual error message would also be helpful

Comment: If I had to guess, perhaps the mangled name is overflowing internal buffers the linker and the compiler. If your typedefs are themselves inside a namespace, try taking them out and see if the problem goes away. Nonetheless a segfault is no matter what a compiler or linker bug, and you should submit them to the GCC bugzilla with a simple test case.

Comment: The actual error message is also posted above. That is the only message that I get

Comment: It would be helpful to have the version of `g++` you are using, to try and reproduce :)

Comment: Thread model: posix
gcc version 3.3.3 (SuSE Linux)
g++: no input files

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a compiler/linker bug: no C++ code should ever cause segfaults in the compiler/linker.

By the way, how do you get this code to compile? How is `pointer` declared?

```
Class1Tuple tup("str", pointer);
ClassTupleItem(tup); // works fine since I used Class1Tuple

Class6Tuple tup2("str", pointer);
ClassTupleItem(tup2); // causes a segfault.
```

If the classes are declared like this, for `Class1Tuple`, `pointer` should be a `shared_ptr<Class1>`, and for `Class6Tuple` it should be of a different type, `shared_ptr<Class6>`.

```
struct Class1
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class1> Ptr;
    /* ... */
};

/* ... */

struct Class6
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class6> Ptr;
    /* ... */
};
```

**Edit:** The following code compiles correctly with g++ 3.3.6. I am not able to test it on gcc 3.3.3 and SUSE Linux at the moment. Please try to compile this and see if the linker still gives a segfault.

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <string>

struct Class1
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class1> Ptr;
    /* .... */
};

struct Class2
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class2> Ptr;
    /* .... */
};

struct Class3
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class3> Ptr;
    /* .... */
};

struct Class4
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class4> Ptr;
    /* .... */
};

struct Class5
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class5> Ptr;
    /* .... */
};

struct Class6
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class6> Ptr;
    /* .... */
};

struct Class7
{
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<Class7> Ptr;
    /* .... */
};

typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class1::Ptr> Class1Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class2::Ptr> Class2Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class3::Ptr> Class3Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class4::Ptr> Class4Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class5::Ptr> Class5Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class6::Ptr> Class6Tuple;
typedef boost::tuple<std::string, Class7::Ptr> Class7Tuple;

typedef boost::variant< Class1Tuple, Class2Tuple, Class3Tuple,
                        Class4Tuple, Class5Tuple, Class6Tuple,
                        Class7Tuple > ClassTupleItem;

int main()
{
    Class1::Ptr pointer;
    Class1Tuple tup("str", pointer);
    (ClassTupleItem(tup)); // Temporary object
    ClassTupleItem item(tup);

    Class6::Ptr pointer2;
    Class6Tuple tup2("str", pointer2);
    (ClassTupleItem(tup2)); // Temporary object
    ClassTupleItem item2(tup2);
}
```

Comment: Then you shouldn't be able to costruct a `Class6Tuple` object with a `Class1::Ptr` when it expects a `Class6::Ptr`... unless an implicit conversion is taking place.

Comment: mistake in posting code. these two are defined in their own if blocks in the actual code and pointer for each is declared with its own class

Comment: By the way, this code shouldn't compile (and it doesn't on gcc 3.3.6); the compiler sees the second line as a re-declaration of `tup`: `Class1Tuple tup("str", pointer); ClassTupleItem(tup);`